# Android: ERROR: Cause: compileSdkVersion is not specified

Tags: android, android-studio

I have seen many similar questions, but none of the solutions fixed my problem. I get the following error on Android Studio ERROR:

> Cause: compileSdkVersion is not specified.

My code on `build.gradle` file inside the app folder is the following:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.adam.modernartuivangelis"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.41"
}
```

I also migrated to Android X, but still the same problem

Comment: Why don't you move your application to Android x and keep target SDk to 29. Anyways play store is not accepting apps whose target sdk is below 28.

Comment: remove buildToolsVersion

Comment: @PrashantSable I did migrate, but still the same error

Comment: @GaneshPokale I did this but again same error

Comment: BuildToolsVersion is not required. Try removing it.

Comment: @PrashantSable Please see edits

Comment: @Maverick98 try reimporting the project in Android Studio.

Comment: @Maverick98 Good to know. Consider upvoting my comments, if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Path: `android/app/build.gradle`

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.awesomeproject"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Add this line to defaultConfig: `compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion`